# How to read a file containing matrix into a vector of vectors?

Tags: java

I have a file containing data in the following format:

```
5
11 24 07 20 03
04 12 25 08 16
17 05 13 21 09
10 18 01 14 22
23 06 19 02 15
3
04 09 02
03 05 07
08 01 06
```

The first number tells the size of the square matrix and the lines following that number are the elements of the matrix separated by spaces.

How do I read this data into a vector of vectors? Sorry, I am new to programming. How do I make sure that once the program gets the size it reads that exact number of lines of the matrix? There will be many matrices, so how do I clear the vectors after I have passed the values to the appropriate functions?

I don't think the code I did would make any sense to you, but here it is...

```
File file = new File("magic.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] lineArr = line.split(" ");
        int[] elements = new int[lineArr.length];
        int size = sc.nextInt();

        Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix = new Vector<>(size);
        Vector<Integer> row = new Vector<>(size);

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                row.add(j, elements[i]);
            }
            matrix.add(i, row);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(matrix.get(i).get(j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Vector`? It's an old, mostly obsolete, class. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) even says so: *If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is **recommended to use `ArrayList`** in place of `Vector`.*

Comment: Why are you using `DataInputStream`? You're not even using anything it adds.

Comment: I have to use Vectors because of my professor. He won't allow us to use any other data structures yet :(

Yeah I just realized I could just use the scanner for input.

Comment: Apparently he met James Gosling and talked to him about Java back when Gosling had launched it. So he is quite old haha.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. It seems that you didn´t make any research before asking.

Comment: I made an account on SO just because I couldn't find anything anywhere else. Everyone is using 2D arrays or array lists. I have updated my code with some changes. Please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Comments about your code:

- You should use try-with-resources.
- Remove `DataInputStream`. You're not even using what is adds.
- Don't use `Vector`, use `List` instead. Or build an `int[][]`, since you know the size.
- Don't declare `rows` and `columns` before the loops.

Here is example of what code could be:

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(line);

        List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if ((line = br.readLine()) == null)
                throw new EOFException();

            List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String value : line.split(" "))
                row.add(Integer.parseInt(value));
            matrix.add(row);
        }

        System.out.println(matrix);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
[[11, 24, 7, 20, 3], [4, 12, 25, 8, 16], [17, 5, 13, 21, 9], [10, 18, 1, 14, 22], [23, 6, 19, 2, 15]]
[[4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 7], [8, 1, 6]]
```

As mentioned earlier, you could also build a 2D array instead:

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(line);

        int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if ((line = br.readLine()) == null)
                throw new EOFException();

            String[] values = line.split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(values[j]);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I understand other data structures might be more effective for this task but I have to use vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classical task for Stream API

```
        File file = new File("your-file-path-here");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, size)
                    .mapToObj(row ->
                            IntStream.range(0, size)
                                    .mapToObj(i -> scanner.next())
                                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```